# Infer types between modules' callbacks locally scoped

Tags: typescript

I would like to find a way to support a generic type for a callback that can pass resulting locally scoped types as usage defines it to another module.

So far I have this common structure in my project (comments explain problem a bit more).

```
// in file other.d.ts
type queryCb = <T>(err: any, result: T) => void

// in file A.ts
export module A {

    export const getDetails = (arg:number, callback:queryCb) => {

        interface details {
            aDetail: number
        }

        let err:string = "Potentially found from database query."
        let newDetails: details = { aDetail: arg + 1 }

        callback(err, newDetails) // (parameter) callback: <details>(err: any, result: details) => void (seems fine?)
    }

}

// in file B.ts
export module B {

    export const doDetails = () => {

      A.getDetails(2, (err, result) => { // result is T here, would like to have it as `details`
        console.log(result)
      })

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does moving the interface out of the function and explicitly typing the callback work for your use case?

```js
export module A {
    interface details {
            aDetail: number
    }
    type queryCb<T> = (err: any, result: T) => void;

    export const getDetails = (arg:number, callback: queryCb<details>) => {
        let err:string = "Potentially found from database query."
        let newDetails: details = { aDetail: arg + 1 }

        callback(err, newDetails) // (parameter) callback: <details>(err: any, result: details) => void (seems fine?)
    }
}

export module B {
    export const doDetails = () => {
      A.getDetails(2, (err, result) => { // result is now `details`
        console.log(result)
      })
   }
}
```

Comment: that is certainly a potential solution, but would prefer the locally scoped interface **if possible...**